# PHP - caminho do diretório

Tags: php, url

Estou fazendo um site que tem uma coluna chamada *-News-*, essa coluna eu chamo através do `include`. *(vocês podem imaginar que é um arquivo externo - news.php)*, até ai normal.

Acontece que no meu site existem pastas em outros níveis, por exemplo:

- index.php
- news.php
- content/acao/index.php
- content/material/index.php
- content/util/index.php

São mais ou menos 10 pastas com a mesma estrutura.

Na página principal (`index.php`), estou incluindo o *news.php* da seguinte maneira:

```
$path = "news.php" ; 
include $path;
```

Até ai normal.

Acontece que quando quando chamo o mesmo arquivo nos *index* que tem subníveis, a minha *URL* perde a referência.

```
$path = "../../news.php" ; 
include $path;
```

O campo *news* aparece nas minhas páginas, mas quando clico em um *link* a *URL* aparece errada. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
content/news/2018/acao/news/2018/index.php
```

Gostaria de saber se existe algo, que faça o *PHP*, das subpastas, voltar ao nível pai (vamos dizer assim).

Tentei utilizar `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`, porém não deu certo. `dirname($path)` também não deu certo.

Evidentemente o PHP esta correto na sua leitura, mas se puderem me ajudar a resolver esse problema, serei grato.

Comment: news.php está na pasta raiz do seu projeto, e o $path que está dando erro ao dar include é o dentro de content/acao/index.php?

Comment: isso mesmo ! o $path está no index do acao...

Comment: Utilize `set_include_path('/path/to')` no seus *index.php* ou utilize o caminho completo `include "/path/to/news.php";` ou utilize `rewrite` (como uma espécie de URL amigável).

Comment: legal... vou experimentar o que vc disse ... (y)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$raiz = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
include $raiz . "news.php";
```

Assim você sempre pega o host do site e não precisa se preocupa em qual pagina é chamado o `include`.

Se você for usar o `include` para outros arquivos que estão dentro de alguma pasta faça desta forma:

```
$raiz = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
include $raiz . "content/util/index.php";
```

Assim você precisa pensar no caminho a partir da raiz.

Fiz a seguinte função para facilitar as coisas:

```
function caminho($path){
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path;
    $barras = array('\\', '/');
    return str_replace($barras,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$path);
}
include caminho("news.php");
```

Comment: Testei as duas alternativas que você me encaminhou, mas não deu certo. A página não dá erro, mas o arquivo news.php não é carregado. Será que existe algo que tenho que instalar ou configurar?

Comment: Editei a resposta, tente desta forma.

Comment: ..olha, sinceramente não sei o que está acontecendo. Fiz exatamente o que vc me aconselhou fazer. Erro na página não acontece, mas o news.php não aparece .. utilizando a função que vc fez. Preciso subir o site no domínio para poder ver as alterações? (é tenho que fazer esse tipo de pergunta)  =\